# Installation problems with Gimp 2.8 on Kubuntu 12

Tags: apt, kubuntu, gimp

I've just upgraded to Kubuntu 12.04 and having problems installing Gimp 2.8, I was wondering if anyone can help me?

I've followed these instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

but get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
gimp : Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried running these and trying again with the same problems:

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

also running

```
sudo apt-get install  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

gives me this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libgail18 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and then running

```
sudo apt-get install  libgail18
```

gives me this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgail18 : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.10-0ubuntu6) but 2.24.10-1oneiric6~ppa is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The bit that caught my attention was **but 2.24.10-1oneiric6~ppa is to be installed** - but I don't know what to do with this.  I've rebooted and the error messages are the same.  Can anyone help?

** EDIT **
I've found someone with the same problem, unfortunately the link is in German so I can't completely understand what the solution (last post) is - here's the google translated link : http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3A1U2Uat6XqUsJ%3Aforum.ubuntuusers.de%2Ftopic%2Fprobleme-nach-update-fehlerhafte-pakete-aus-on%2F%2B%26cd%3D3%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Duk&act=url

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove the gimp 2.8 repo by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
```

And then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now remove the plugin-registery as it is not supported on 2.8:

```
sudo apt-get remove gimp-plugin-registry
```

Once that’s done you can install Gimp 2.8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

After Gimp 2.8 is installed successfully, here's how you can install plugin-registry on gimp 2.8.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/install-gimp-plugin-registry-for-gimp.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply - having done all of the above I've still got the same issue.  Full output here : http://pastebin.com/PCMN0Min

Comment: No prob, here's what you need to do.

Install synaptic package manager and search for Gimp related files.

Remove all Gimp relating files. Also check if you can run the repair for broken packages in synaptic.

Comment: I've done this and have removed everything I can see which is explicitly gimp related but still getting the same error message.  Here're the left over installed items when searching for gimp - http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qxrp0o&s=6

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

I also had this problem, must have tried every command of `apt-get`, purging the repository, manually deleting all other source lists under `/etc/apt`, updating, `/etc` - but still the package manger was saying that it wanted to install the `2.24.10-1oneiric6~ppa` version even though I knew that there was no trace (that I knew of) of any ppa for apt-get.

I tried playing around with `aptitude` and that downgraded `libgtk2.0-0` for me and everything started installing correctly.  I don't remember exactly what I used since I really only use aptitude to search for packages in my `konsole` but searching for `libgtk2` then marking it for upgrade did the trick.  Incomplete directions below and ignore the quotes:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude

press "/" to start searching
type in the name of the offending package
you may have to press "/" then enter again, do until you find it
press "+" to upgrade or "i" to install
This is when aptitude offered to downgrade
press "g" to do the upgrade/installation
```

You and also use the mouse to click on the words to do the same.